# Preserve newlines in Twitter Oneboxes

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox

For several years now, Twitter supports newlines in tweets.

However, when oneboxed in chat, the lines are lost and it's showing everything in one line.

For example, compare the following:

[image]

[image]

Can newlines in oneboxed tweets be preserved please?

One possible solution is applying the following CSS:

```
.ob-status-text {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```